# Motion along length of a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, velocity, spring, elasticity

What's relation between velocity of each part of a massive spring undergoing Simple Harmonic Motion.

Comment: What did you try? What assumptions do you make? Think how distance of part of the spring is connected to distance of the end of the spring, and how this relates to the velocities of these parts.

Comment: Hi. Homework-like questions should be asked with a description of your approach to the question and with the specification as to what particular conceptual points are puzzling you. That said, for this question, I would suggest thinking in light of the fact that the strain is constant throughout the length in an ideal spring.

Comment: I read somewhere that a spring of mass m can be considered as a massless spring with a mass of m/3 attached to its end. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: This is a whole different (and more complicated) question. For a massive spring, you need to calculate the standing wave frequencies (in which case, you also no longer assume that displacement is proportional to the distance).

Comment: In which case, the fundamental standing wave frequency of a spring attached on one side is given by $\omega^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{k}{m}$, comparing to $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$ for massless spring with a mass at the end. Comparison tells you that the frequencies match when a massless spring has $\frac{4}{\pi^2}m$ of its own mass at the end (which is not exactly a third, more like 0.4).

Comment: Let me simply, There's a spring of mass m and natural length l. , one end of which is fixed and other is moving with velocity v, I need to find velocity of a small part of spring which is at x distance from fixed part of spring.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi$ be an unextended length (coordinate) measured along the spring from its left end, and let u represent the displacement to the right of the particular cross section situated at unextended coordinate $\xi$ when the spring is stretched.  If the spring is stretched uniformly, then $$\frac{du}{d\xi}=\frac{u}{\xi}=\frac{U}{L}$$where U is the displacement of the right end of the spring at $\xi=L$ and $du/d\xi$ is the uniform axial strain.  Also, for uniform stretching of the spring, the tension in the spring is uniform, and given by:
$$T=kU=(kL)\frac{du}{d\xi}$$where k is the overall spring constant.

Under circumstances where the spring is stretched non-uniformly, the local tension in the spring (at unstretched coordinate $\xi$) is still determined by the local strain, and given by:$$T(\xi,t)=(kL)\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}$$where the above equation assumes that the displacement and tension are also changing with time.

If we perform a differential force balance on the section of the spring between $\xi$ to $\xi+\Delta \xi$, we obtain:$$\frac{M}{L}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}\Delta \xi=T(t,\xi+\Delta \xi)-T(t,\xi)$$Taking the limit as $\Delta \xi$ approaches zero then yields:
$$\frac{M}{L}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}=(kL)\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi^2}$$or equivalently,
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{kL^2}{M}\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi^2}$$This is the longitudinal wave equation for the spring.